# Parse error codes 209 and -34018

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have spent several hours learning user management on Parse, thinking it would be easy considering it's been an established service for so long.

There is poor documentation around 'automatic user' and sessions.

I am trying to build an App that allows the user to exist anonymously (using `[PFUser enableAutomaticUser]`), before they decide to sign up.

Registration Steps:

1. Gather user details from the UI
2. Log out current automatic user and wait for success
3. Upon success create a user object using `[PFUser user]` and assign values
4. Call `signUpInBackgroundWithBlock` on the new user instance

I sometimes get the following errors (yes, only sometimes), when doing the above.

> [Error]: PFKeychainStore failed to get object for key 'currentUser', with error: -34018
>
> [Error]: invalid session token (Code: 209, Version: 1.7.0)

I also end up with a dirty database, because I don't know how to delete the automatic user that was previously created.  I tried keeping the object id of the old user around and using `deleteEventually` but that didn't work?

Any advice on how you would go about achieving this would be great.

Comment: My guess is that the cached user is not being deleted. Have you tried something like creating the new user in clouded, passing the user token back and then using becomeUser on the client?

Comment: I'm having the same issue: PFKeychainStore failed to get object for key 'currentUser', with error: -34018

Comment: You don't have to delete the current user before signing up, just treat it as a regular user and when you call `signUp` it will be converted from an anon user.

Comment: im not sure about this...but would it make sense to set the user you are creating `[PFUser user]` as `currentUser` before `signUpInBackgroundWithBlock` executes? Maybe `PFUser *x = [PFUser user]; [PFUser currentUser] = x`? I'm not sure if you can set `currentUser` like that, but its worth a shot if this is relevant.

Comment: I get this error when I was login with one user in two location and then I logout from on the two location. Then the session on the other location is invalidated and you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is a bug of keychain, you can search it at github.

[Github 34018 issues](https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&q=34018&ref=searchresults&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

A few months ago, some apple's staff came our company to give us a course, after course,we asked this question, they also did't give us a solution

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by using the following:

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
[user refreshInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Succesfully refreshed the current user.");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to refresh the current user with error %@", error);
        }
}];
```

It seems that `[PFUser currentUser]` returns an invalid session token which is causing the 209 and -34018 errors. This is only an issue when the current user is an anonymous user.