# PFKeychainStore Error -34018

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've been getting this error on occasion from within iOS:

```
PFKeychainStore failed to get object for key 'currentUser', with error: -34018
```

Sometimes it occurs when I sign up, and sometimes later.  I'm not using Facebook or Twitter to login; just the conventional signUp and login functions (e.g.,
User.logInWithUsernameInBackground).

Any idea of what is causing it and what it means?  It appears others have been seeing this as well. ([Parse error codes 209 and -34018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027028/parse-error-codes-209-and-34018))